# for loop that produces series of different numbers

Tags: java, for-loop

I have found a few similar topics to my issue, but couldn't figure out the task still, so I thought it'd be best to create my own topic.

I need to write a for loop that produces the following output:

289 256 225 196 169 144 121 100 81

For added challenge, try to modify your code so that it does not need to use the * multiplication operator.

This is my code below, I'm stuck here so please help.

```
public class Exercises2{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      int start = 19;
      int increment = 2;
      for(int count = 81; count <= 289; count++){


         System.out.println(count + start);
         start = increment + start;         

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: `for (int i : new int[] {289, 256, 225, 196, 169, 144, 121, 100, 81}) { System.out.println(i); }`? You'd better clarify your question.

Comment: Please explain the pattern of output that the loop needs to produce.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear, but the answers below has pretty much answered my question. I couldn't figure out how to increase my start variable with 2 so I could hit the specific numbers I needed to output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is what you need. Notice the count+=start increment within the for loop and the start+=increment adding from the base of 17 so you increase count by 19 the first time, 21 the second, etc.

Remember a for loop doesn't require a count++ it can be any valid command in the last portion or can be left out completely

```
int start = 17;
int increment = 2;
for(int count = 81; count <= 289; count+=start){
    System.out.println(count);
    start+=increment;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you figured out the pattern for generating the numbers in the series? If not, the multiplication "challenge" is actually a big hint at how it's generated.

After that try to figure out how to write a loop that does multiplication manually and that should give you the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you're not incrementing count enough. If you're going to have count go from 81 to 289 then you need to be doing more to count than just ++; Just a couple changes fixes your own code. Change the start value to 17 and change how count is incremented to count += start.

```
int start = 17;
int increment = 2;
for(int count = 81; count <= 289; count += start){      
    System.out.println(count);
    start += increment;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is value in doing your homework yourself and figuring it out can bring a lot of benefit and gain as a programmer. But here is your answer without multiplication:

```
 int start = 2;

int increment = 19;

int value = 81;

int _max = 289;

while(value <= _max)
{
    System.out.println(value);
    value += increment;
    increment += start;
}
```

Comment: I needed a for-loop, but I appreciate your support. I have tried to figure it out myself, but I got stuck that is why I'm seeking help, shouldn't be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    int start=17;  
    int end=9;     
    for(int i=17;i>=9;i--)
    {
        System.out.println (i*i);

    }
```